# How do you run multiple grunt scripts.postinstall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I'm trying to run multiple CLI commands from scripts.postinstall of grunt.  I can't figure out how to get both to run. If I add the second command neither run.  Separately they both work on postinstall and in the console.

I've tried wrapping them in an array:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": ["node_modules/.bin/bower install", "grunt setup"]
},
```

I tried separating them with a semi-colon:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/bower install; grunt setup"
  },
```

I can't seem to find the solution on [NPM Scripts](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html)

My gruntfile.js for these sections look like this:

```
mkdir: {
    setup: {
        options: {
            create: [
                'app/main/source/www', 'app/main/build', 'app/main/docs', 'app/main/tests',
                'app/development',
                'app/releases'
            ]
        }
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('setup', [
    'mkdir:setup',
    'bowercopy:wordpress'
]);
```

In case it helps here's a parred down version of my package.json that I snipped the above code examples, mostly to provide context.

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A web app using bower and grunt",
  "main": "gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/bower install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "someurl.com"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "web", "app"
  ],
  "author": {
    "company": "somecompany",
    "name": "somename",
    "email": "email@me.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://someurl.com",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "someurl.com"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "bower" : "~1.3.5",
    etc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use && to run multiple commands in the npm scripts section

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install && grunt setup"
},
```

Comment: you can't do this on windows.

Comment: I use Windows primarily and have used this technique before. It can work

Comment: @kobe yes it should be fine. `&&` is standard shell scripting operator, it's not node specific

Answer (score 11):

You could try writing a Bash script that executes those two commands and run that instead.

post_install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
node_modules/.bin/bower install
grunt setup
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./post_install.sh"
  },
```

Comment: Hi Chris, at first it seemed to work, but it appears to fail somewhere as bower install doesn't pull down the dependencies, and grunt setup doesn't create the project file heirarchy.  It does seem to run postinstall though???  How would you debug this?  There doesn't appear to be any errs.

Comment: Sorry Chris, works great.  For whatever reason I had sublime text opening .sh files by default with my text editor.  So it would "run" post_install.sh, but really it just tried to reopen what I already had open in sublime

Comment: I get permission errors and FYI I cannot use sudo, as I will be working in Docker.